# Differing definitions of the Characteristic Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

According to the definition of an eigenvalue it satisfies the equation

$Ax=\lambda x$ where $A\in M_{n\times n}^{\mathbb{F}}$.

So that we could have either:

$(A-\lambda I)x=0$ or $(\lambda I-A)x=0$

such that the characteristic equation is either

$det(A-\lambda I)=0$ or $det(\lambda I-A)=0$.

What practical differences result from the two possible definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no difference in the roots of the characteristic equation.

$
\left| \left(
\begin{matrix}
a_{11} - \lambda & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} - \lambda & & \\
. \\
. \\
. \\
a_{n1} & ... & & a_{nn} - \lambda
\end{matrix}
\right) \right|
= 
(-1)^n \left| \left(
\begin{matrix}
\lambda - a_{11}  & - a_{12} & ... & - a_{1n} \\
- a_{21} & \lambda - a_{22} & & \\
. \\
. \\
. \\
-a_{n1} & ... & & \lambda - a_{nn}
\end{matrix}
\right) \right|
$

If $P(x)$ has a root $r$, then $-P(x)$ will have the same root.

Comment: So in second case $det(A)=(-1)^n*c_0$ where $c_0$ is the constant term of $P(x)$?

Comment: Here I've used the notation det(A) = |A|. Notice that the matrix on the LHS is $(A - \lambda I)$ and the matrix on the RHS is $(\lambda I - A)$. One property of det(A) is that if we multiply a row of A by a scalar c, the determinant becomes c*det(A). Now notice that $(\lambda I - A)$ is the same matrix we get by multiplying each row of $(A - \lambda I)$ by $(-1)$. So, we have $det(A - \lambda I) = (-1)^n det(\lambda I - A)$.

Comment: Yeah, according to this it looks like what I said is correct:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html

Answer (score 2):

Since $\det(cX) = c^n\det(X) $for an $n×n$ matrix, both are equivalent for even $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the characteristic polynomial is$\det(\lambda I-A)$
and not $\det(A-\lambda I)$ because if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix
then the characteristic polynomial would of had a leading coefficient$-1$
and not $1$ for odd $n$.

In any case, there is not big difference here since if $\det(\lambda I-A)=P(\lambda)$
then $\det(A-\lambda I)=-P(\lambda)$ and in particular they have
the same roots.

Also note $(\lambda I-A)x=0\iff(A-\lambda I)x=0$

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but you should take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Formal_definition

Comment: I downvoted for several reasons: (i) stating that the definition $\det(A - \lambda I)$ is "wrong"; (ii) writing "would of had"; and (iii) stating that $\det(A - \lambda I) = -\det(\lambda I - A)$.